# How to scrape the description in google search results

Tags: .net, parsing, browser, scrape

Im developing an application using vb.net , my application will do simple search on google using webbrowser control the the application will scrape the results Links and their description , I have succeeded to scrape the href of the links but I can't scrape the description of search results for each link !

any help will be highly appreciated

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This violates Google's terms of service.

Comment: Why you don't use http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/dev_guide.html?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why anyone decided to remove my response from yesterday.
It was accurate and a good help for him but I guess we've people here with a god complex just like on Wikipedia.

I'll not write the whole s* again, sorry:
Check the information on http://google-scraper.squabbel.com . It includes all you need to solve your issue, you just need to convert the PHP code to VB/NET code.